# How to show couple of columns with COUNT() func in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with MySQL. I have two tables. First with `clicks`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clicks(
    id VARCHAR(255),
    link VARCHAR(255),
    clickDate INT
    );
```

and second with `visits`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS visits(
    id VARCHAR(255),
    ip INT,
    browser VARCHAR(255)
    );
```

The `id` values is the same for two tables. My goal is to get result table with such columns:

`ip` | `clicks_quantity` | `clickDate` | `browser`

For now I can get result table with `ip` | `clicks_quantity`.
My SQL request is:

```
SELECT
    visits.ip,
    count(visits.ip) as clicks_quantity,
FROM
    visits
INNER JOIN
    clicks ON visits.id=clicks.id
WHERE
    clicks.clickDate BETWEEN 1 and 7
GROUP BY
    visits.ip
```

My question is - How to get table with two additional columns?

`ip` | `clicks_quantity` | **`clickDate`** | **`browser`**

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
SELECT v.ip, count(*) as clicks_quantity,
       v.browser,
       group_concat(distinct c.clickDate) as clickDates
FROM visits v INNER JOIN
     clicks c
     ON v.id= c.id
WHERE c.clickDate BETWEEN 1 and 7
GROUP BY v.ip, v.browser;
```

You can have multiple `clickDates` based on the data model.  You don't specify what to do with them, so concatenating distinct values in a string seems like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the following query to get clicks quantity based on browser and ip and click date

```
SELECT visits.ip, clicks.clickDate, visits.browser, count(visits.ip) as clicks_quantity FROM visits INNER JOIN clicks ON visits.id=clicks.id WHERE clicks.clickDate BETWEEN 1 and 7 GROUP BY visits.ip,clicks.clickDate, visits.browser
```